# Is it possible to save ComboBox results that uses.addItem(...)?

Tags: java, save, loading, jcombobox

I am considering using the following code:

```
comboBox.addItem(...);
```

If I continue using this code to add items to the comboBox, would it be possible to save the items into either a text file or memory? *so that it can be loaded in the next time the user wants to use the gui.

Thanks for any help you may provide. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I would recommend creating a class that serializes the object to a text file. This can be accomplished with Input/Output Streams or the File class.

So you would take the array of objects, then serialize the object to a text file, then read it back into the array the next time the program runs.

Here is some info on Serializable: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html
File Class: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html